# COUNTIFS returning 0 with a third calculation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm clearly doing something stupid and obvious to the trained eye, but I'm an untrained eye unfortunately!

I have the following Formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('GD Grey & Yellow'!N:N,"Group 1", 'GD Grey & Yellow' !F:F, "NULL", 'GD Grey & Yellow'!F:F, "PC")
```

This works fine until I put in the third criteria and range? It just comes back zero. It works fine with two of any criteria, but not the three. What the chuff am I doing wrong??

Comment: Check your logic with a pencil and paper. This is usually the problem I find. Also, a Zero is FALSE === not found. Also, not knowing or being able to see your work, I have to ask myself what how is null defined; null, NULL, or "NULL", or how does Excel see a null value or absent value or no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to examine properly without a print-screen or example, but I think it has to do something with using the `'GD Grey & Yellow' !F:F` criteria range two times with different criterion.

I think you were going for the OR Boolean expression, but you used AND instead - meaning: count the cells in `'GD Grey & Yellow' !F:F` which are both `'NULL'` AND `'PC'` which will give you the result as zero, as these criteria cannot happen at the same time.

If this is the case, this modification (breaking into two pieces) might help:

```
=COUNTIFS('GD Grey & Yellow'!N:N,"Group 1", 'GD Grey & Yellow' !F:F, "NULL") + COUNTIFS('GD Grey & Yellow'!N:N,"Group 1", 'GD Grey & Yellow'!F:F, "PC")
```

Comment: or possibly, `countif("Yellow'!N:N, "GroupX") + countif('Yellow'!F:F', "NULL") + countif...`